# " not captured " Error in std::all_of() C++

Tags: c++

When I use value in all_of pred function it works but when I use variable it gives error. Whyy??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<int> a{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
   
   int x=10;
   
   if(std::all_of(a.cbegin(),a.cend(),[](int i){return i< x; }))
   {
       cout<<"all elements are smaller than x";
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

It Gives error but this doesn't.

```
if(std::all_of(a.cbegin(),a.cend(),[](int i){return i< 10; }))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) your variables inside your lambda:

```
if(std::all_of(a.cbegin(),a.cend(),[x](int i){return i< x; }))
//                                  ^ here
```

This captures `x` by value.

Comment: Please post one more example of capturing by reference for completeness.